# Maya file node query color space

Tags: file, maya

Is there a way to query a texture file node color space in maya? i.e. raw, sRGB and etc. I know how to write it but not query it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to query the available color spaces:

```
color_spaces = cmds.colorManagementPrefs(q=True, renderingSpaceNames=True)
print(color_spaces)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `listConnections` to get a list of texture files connected to your material, then simply use `getAttr` to query it:

```
# Example of having a texture file on a Blinn's color property.
texture_files = cmds.listConnections("blinn1.color", type="file")
if texture_files:
    print cmds.getAttr("{}.colorSpace".format(texture_files[0]))

# Result: sRGB
```

Comment: Thanks that works. Is there a way to query available color spaces?

Comment: I'm not sure. Check the `cmds` docs for `colorManagementFileRules`